# C# map two complex objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have four classes :

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string ProductColor { get; set; }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Customer_
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Article> Article { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int ArticleNumber { get; set; }

    public string ArticleColor { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance :

```
var Cus = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName1",
        LastName = "LastName1",
        Product = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product()
            {
                ProductColor = "ProductColor1",
                ProductNumber = 11
            }
        }
    },               
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName2",
        LastName = "LastName2",
        Product = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product()
            {
                ProductColor = "ProductColor2",
                ProductNumber = 12
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to create a new object `List<Customer_>` with the value of my instance `Cus`. For example `Customer.FirstName = Customer_.FirstName, Customer.Product.ProductColor = Customer_.Article.ArticleColor etc`

What is the best way to do this easily, could one use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) ?

Comment: You have a dictionary tag on this and, as asked, this question has no mention of dictionaries?

Comment: Failing automapper reflection, failing reflection a constructor in Customer_ taking customer.  This example is artificial, in your real use case how many fields / properties do you need to set?   Also do you have any mutable reference types that need copying and do you expect that copy to be reference or a second level of cloning?  IS generics an option?  ie a customer<T> where T is Article or Product?

Comment: In my real case I have ~ 100 propriety in my main clas and ~ 10 sub class

Comment: In particular what do you expect to happen with the List<Product> => List<Article>?

Answer (score 3):

Mapping can be accomplished through the use of an [`Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx).

---

Define an interface(s) which provide a mapping of logically named properties such as the common color properties you mention:

```
// Some entities have different named properties but can be joined
// using those properties. This interface shows a common color which 
// when implemented will route the processing to a common shared property
// which reports and sets the associated color.
public interface IDefinedColor
{
    string Color { get; set; }
}
```

If you have to create `partial` classes for `Product` and `Article` and have them adhere to said interfaces. *Hint if using an entity mapper such as EF this is a great way to do such maping using partials*. Implement implement the interface and hook up the commonality:

```
// Holds the common properties for future processing.
public partial class Product : IDefinedColor
{
    public string Color
    {
        get { return ProductColor; }
        set { ProductColor = value; }
    }
}
```

Then work off of the `IDefinedColor` *mapped* implementations as needed.

---

By using interfaces one is letting all future developers know of the contract which specifies a business logic equality in the properties and it is not hidden in other *joining* classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mapper extension class

```
public static class MapperExtension
{

public Customer_ Convert(this Customer customer)
{
   return new Customer_()
   {
     FirstName = customer.FirstName,
     LastName = customer.LastName,
     Article = customer.Product.Convert()
   };
}

public static List<Article> Convert(this List<Product> products)
{
    return products.Select(x=> new Article(){
    ArticleNumber = x.ProductNumber,
    ArticleColor = x.ProductColor
    };
}
}
```

make sure you reference the proper namespace where you place the extension class.

Call the code like this

Where customers is a List filled from your code

```
List<Customer_> convertedCustomers_ = customers.Select(x=> x.Convert()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationhip between those components but I would simply add constructor to Customer_ that accepts a Customer object. And then you invoke that do perform the conversion. e.g.

```
public class Article
{
   public Article(Product source)
   {
      this.ArticleNumber = source.ProductNumber;
      this.ArticleColor = source.ProductColor;
   }
}

public class Customer_
{
    public Customer_(Customer source) 
    {
        this.FirstName = source.FirstName;
        this.LastName = source.LastName;
        this.Article = source.Product.Select(o => new Article(o)).ToList()
    }

    ...
}

//and finally to convert the list you can do something like

//initial list
var Cus = new List<Customer>() { ... etc. }

/converted list
var Cus_ = Cus.Select(o => new Cusomter_(o)).ToList();
```

Edit: I see from your comment above that you actually have 100 properties to map. I can see this is a pain. But if you have complex transformations like Product to Article then I would still go the manual route as above so you can be completely clear about what is going on. Alternatively you could look to use inheritance to redesign your objects with common base classes or interfaces, that would probably make mapping easier.