# Unable to cast 2 objects although they share same interface

Tags: c#

I would like to map 2 objects but I don't want to rely on 3rd party tools - the reason is to help me get a better understanding of what those 3rd party tools may do.

I have an interface, which has `string` `Foo` and `bool` `Bar`

```
public interface ITest
{
    string Foo { get; set; }
    bool Bar { get; set; }
}
```

My first class, called `A` implements ITest

```
public class A : ITest
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public bool Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, Class `B` also implements ITest but has an additional property

```
public class B : ITest
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public bool Bar { get; set; }
    public int Other { get; set; }
}
```

Since both classes share a common interface, how can I cast one to the other?

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
a= b as A; //does not work but this would be ideal
```

I don't want to Map by explicitly stating the names of the properties.

As such, having (where the B constructor maps) is also not ideal

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B(a); //not desired
```

Is this possible? It would mean that only the properties that were defined in the interface would be copied across.

Answers like [C# map two complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484065/c-sharp-map-two-complex-objects) are not ideal as I have to explicitly state the properties.

Comment: But `B` isn't an `A`. It might have an interface in common,  but that's it.

Comment: Why not cast it to an `ITest` instead?

Comment: @Sean how do I cast to ITest? :/ I'm sorry, I'm new to interfaces

Comment: Based on your intended usage, it seems you are needing to implement an inheritance between A (base) and B (derived), rather than using a shared interface between them. But since you don't actually explain the problem that needs to be solved, it's impossible to know if either your class/interface setup is wrong or the way in which you intend to use it.

Comment: @Flater the goal is to simply map 2 objects. This means, in the future, if I add another property to the Interface, and implement it in `A` and `B`, I don't also have to update any "map" method

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions - the same way you cast to a class: `var x = b as ITest'

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: You presume that using a shared interface is the correct approach here, but your expected code usage is a completely different approach that cannot be achieved using a shared interface. Hence why I'm saying that it's impossible to know which one of your two contradicting statements (setup vs expectation) is wrong. This is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't ask about your proposed solution, ask about **the actual problem** you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Sean: `ITest x = b` is more idiomatic

Comment: *"I don't want to Map by explicitly stating the names of the properties"*, I don't see anything wrong this that. Tools like `AutoMapper` facilititate that quite nicely.

Comment: @Flater `ITest x = b` is not the same as `var X = b as ITest`

Comment: @Sean: It is the same. What would you suggest is the difference between them?

Comment: I would have thought 1 will throw a null exception reference?

Comment: @Flater: `ITest x = b` won't compile if `b` isn't an `ITest`. `var x = b as ITest` will set 'x` to `null` if `b` isn't an `ITest`

Comment: There are tools out there that can help; [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) is probably the most famous.

Comment: @Sean: I stand corrected, there is a difference. However, avoiding runtime exceptions is a plus, not a drawback.  At best, it works the same; at worst, you've just introduced the possibility for a runtime nullreference. Given that `b`'s type is known anyway, there's no benefit to doing a loose `as` cast, you're essentially just bypassing the compiler's type safety validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json for this.  We do this all the time to cast DataTable into a model.

You Serialize the first model and Deserialize it into the other one.
Doing it this way, only the fields that are in common are touched.

```
        var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };
        string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(A, deserializeSettings);
        B b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(serializedObject);
```

Comment: Arguably the least efficient way to do this, and doesn't handle circular references well.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it's the only option so far that has answered the question. The comments around AutoMapper are also suitable but, as mentioned, I'm trying to learn how I can do this myself :)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions AutoMapper's source is available online... Your declaration that you don't want to use reflection or explicitly naming properties does mean that inefficient methods like serialization routines are the only things left to do. I would strongly discourage its use in a production application though.

Comment: how would it not handle a circular reference?  I use it on a table with included models.  And i challenge anyone to prove this is slower than reflection is.

Answer (score 2):

There is no implicit conversion between `A` and `B`. You can fit both of them in variables of type `ITest`, but that is where the automatics end. C#/.NET is very conserviative with implicit conversions.

And if your example would work, it would also have to work between `System.String` and `System.Windows.Forms.Form` as they both inherit from `Object`. Every Class in .NET implicitly or explicitly inherits from Object, so that would be a nightmare.

What you need to do is either:

- give both classes a proper function for the conversion. Usually a constructor taking a instance of the other type. You could use ITest as the type for those functions. That would keep repitition to a minimum. `A(ITest initializeFrom)`
- write a explicit conversion between those two types:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions
- Actually solve it down to ITest having everything you need, so putting all thoe instances into a ITest variable would give you all you need

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to automatically detect properties and map their values.

```cs
private static T GetMappedObject<T>(object source)
{
    var output = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    var sourceType = source.GetType();

    foreach (var outputProperty in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if (sourceType.GetProperty(outputProperty.Name) is PropertyInfo sourceProperty)
        {
            var value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
            outputProperty.SetValue(output, value);
        }
    }

    return (T)output;
}
```

You can then call this method like `var b = GetMappedObject<B>(a);`.

Note that the above snippet does not check whether the value on the source object can actually be mapped to the output property, and it does require objects of type `T` to define a parameterless constructor.

As someone pointed out in the comments, if not for the educational nature of your question, it is still recommended to use a proven 3rd party tool like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) where you can for production code.

Comment: I am just wondering if is it supposed to use Reflection, why not using a 3rd party tool like `AutoMapper` as `AutoMapper` is using reflection also to map properties, and it is better and easier to use than writing manually! Just it has a little performance overhead because of using Reflection.

Comment: @SalahAkbari The question states that the reason a 3rd party tool cannot be used is because OP wants to learn how those tools work. If they use reflection, then that's a very good reason to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options.

Either cast to the interface `ITest`: `b as ITest`

Make `B` extend `A`. This way casting b to A is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explicit operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators), so something like this maybe what you are looking for:

```
public class A : ITest
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public bool Bar { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator A(B v)
    {
        return new A { Bar = v.Bar, Foo = v.Foo };
    }
}
```

And then use casting instead:

```
a = (A)b;
```

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions What about this/? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: But this is now explicitly mapping the 2 :( ....  As I wrote `I don't want to Map by explicitly stating the names of the properties`

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions You have just set it once in the class, so you don't have to repeat it every time you want to map, also you didn't still use 3rd party tools.

Comment: No, but I change the interface, I have to change the mappnig...

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions So you don't want to Map by explicitly stating the names of the properties, you don't want to use any 3rd party tool, you don't want to use `explicit operator` or any other solution like this, I am really wondering what are you looking for exactly, I hope someone provide you the solution you need! I am curious as well.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions You may also find the useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257215/which-is-the-best-approach-automapper-against-implicit-c-reference

Answer (score 0):

Both classes implement `ITest` interface BUT class `B` also has an extra property which prevents you from casting between the `A` and `B`.

You can however have functions that handle `ITest`, but treat them differently e.g.

```
public void SaveDataFunction(ITest param)
{
    if (param is A)
    {
        SaveDataTypeA((A)param);
    }
    else if (param is B)
    {
        SaveDataTypeB((B)param);
    }
}

private void SaveDataTypeA(A value)
{
}

private void SaveDataTypeB(B value)
{
}
```